# Get the correct path of a Next JS page that uses Dynamic Routing

Tags: next.js, dynamic-routing

I am trying to store the path into state of my app, so if the user is not logged in and is redirected to `/login` after logging in they can be directed to the correct path.

For example:
Path = `/posts/my-new post`

What I am actually getting is `posts/[pid]` which obvious does not work when I try to redirect to.

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

function App() {
  const router = useRouter()
  const [startUrl, setStartUrl] = useState(router.asPath)
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    if (loggedIn) {
      router.push(startUrl)
    }
  },[loggedIn])
  return (
    <>
      <p>Path = {startUrl}</p>
    </>
  )
}
export default App
```

Answer (score 2):

I found that the router was not ready immediately and hence I need to check that it is ready before setting the value.

I have added a storedURL boolean so this only happens on the first time.

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

function App() {
  const router = useRouter()
  const [startUrl, setStartUrl] = useState("/")
  const [storedUrl, setStoredUrl] = useState("/")
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    if (router.isReady && !storedURL) {
      setStartURL(router.asPath)
      setStoredURL(true)
    }
  },[router.isReady])
  useEffect(() => {
    if (loggedIn) {
      router.push(startUrl)
    }
  },[loggedIn])
  return (
    <>
      <p>Path = {startUrl}</p>
    </>
  )
}
export default App
```

This checks to see if the [next/router hook **isReady**](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#router-object) and that the URL has not already been stored (as otherwise it will update everytime the URL is changed)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're going to want to do is store both the path, and the "query" for the current route, and push that into the router when the user has logged in.

I don't have a next.js project to test this with on hand, but I think if you change your code to what I have below it should work:

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

function App() {
  const router = useRouter()
  const [startUrl, setStartUrl] = useState({
        pathname: router.asPath, 
        query: router.query
    })
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    if (loggedIn) {
      router.push(startUrl)
    }
  },[loggedIn])
  return (
    <>
      <p>Path = {startUrl}</p>
    </>
  )
}
export default App
```

See the [next.js useRouter() documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#with-url-object) for more info on the `router.push()` api as used with a URL object.

Comment: Thank you @MykalCodes, I have found the issue. The problem is that next/router is not ready immediately and so this needs to be checked for first, I shall post my solution below.
[next/router ready]{https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8259}